# Replace MVC3 View Engine with Razor v2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to set up our MVC3 apps to use newer versions of Razor? I tried using NuGet, but apparently there must be some additional wiring that needs to be done because I don't see the new features such as URL Resolution and Conditional Attributes working.

Comment: You mean the version associated with MVC 4?  I believe even with the first version, it was dependent on System.Web.Mvc version 3.0, so the same situation would apply here.  It would require the MVC 4.0 dll...

Comment: I have found [this blog post](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-razor-v2-aspnet-mvc-3) which explains how to use Razor V2 in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was asking on the Asp.net forums and found out that the RazorEngine on NuGet is not quite the same thing as the built-in Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install ASP.NET MVC 4
2. Remove the reference to System.Web.WebPages 1.0 and System.Web.Helpers 1.0, then add a reference to System.Web.WebPages 2.0 and System.Web.Helpers 2.0
3. Inside root web.config file, add/update these settings:

   ```
   <appSettings>
       <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
       <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
       <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
   ...
   <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   ...
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
   <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
   ```
4. Inside Views web.config file, add/update these settings:

   ```
   <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
       <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
       <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
   </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
   <system.web.webPages.razor>
       <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   ```